# Django Form Validation Only if User is Not Authenticated?

Tags: python, django

I have a form where I need to check user email only if the user is not already logged in. I know I can check the email in my view but for this form I would prefer to check the email in my form.

with the code below, I'm getting error: `global name 'request' is not defined` inside the clean_email even though the `request` is imported.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_email(self):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email "%s" is already in use!' % email)
            return email
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the request object doesn't go to the form.

But you can easily change the constructor of your form class to receive a user object:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = user
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then you can check if the user is authenticated later on:

```
def clean_email(self):
    if not self.user.is_authenticated():
```

If you really need the whole request object, you just need to add the self, otherwise it tries to access a global variable called request.
i.e:

```
if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
```

And of course, assign the object variable, so it can be accessible from any method of the class:

```
self.request = request
```

Comment: I'm getting `'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'` error with that. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you change the __init__ parameters?

Comment: @WayBehind I saw now that you're already passing the request object, I don't think it's necessary, but in that case you just need to add the self. I updated the answer with this possibilty

Comment: I'm passing the `request` as I'm grabbing `request.session` values for some `initial` values in my form. Now it is working and your response will be accepted!

Answer (score 1):

In the `clean_email` method, you do not automatically have access to the arguments passed to the `__init__` method.

You need to store the `request` in `self.request` in the `__init__` method, then you can access it in the `clean_email` method.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_email(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
```